# find the equation of the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following...
$$z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

I need to write this as an equation in spherical coordinates.

I know that $p^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2$

and that...

$$x = p\sin\phi \cos\theta$$
$$y=p\sin\phi \sin\theta$$
$$z = p\cos\theta$$

The answer is $\phi = \pi/4$

How do you get t0 this answer? I tried doing

$$p^2-z^2 = x^2+y^2$$
$$z^2 = p^2-z^2$$
$$z = p/2$$

But I really do not know what I am doing. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to plug in the values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ in $$z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$
Specifically, by using the given expressions, we get
$$p \cos \phi = \sqrt{p^2\sin^2\phi \cos^2 \theta + p^2\sin^2\theta \sin^2 \phi}$$ $$p \cos\phi = \sqrt{p^2\sin^2 \phi \ (\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta)} $$
$$p \cos\phi = p \sin \phi$$
$$\cos \phi = \sin \phi$$
$$\phi = \pi/4.$$

Comment: Does this result mean that we can describe a cone in polar coordinates only if lattitude is 45 degs?

Answer (score 1):

When latitude is not $\pi/4 $ the following can be said in addition:

$ \phi $ is latitude,$  \,\pi/2-\phi= \alpha $ complementatry or co-latitude, $ r$ radius in  polar ( or in cylindrical coordinates), $\rho$ is in spherical coordinates with

$$ r= \rho \sin \alpha = \rho \cos \phi $$

[image]